# Compression in WebApi hosted on Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, http-compression, azure-api-management

My Web Api is hosted on AzureWebsites and exposed through Azure Api management. I just wondering how the compression will be enabled in such scenario? Will it be something on azurewebsites or it should be done through Api management portal and HOW?

Answer (score 2):

This should enable gzip on every IIS-compatible host:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
      <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Great, Thanks. Will it still work behind AzureApi Management Proxy

Comment: How this would be decompressed in a WinForm application ?

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications As long as you are running in a desktop/console app, decompression will happen automatically. WinInet does it for you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh227298(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This didn't work me locally. The gzip file was not available. The following example did work: http://www.brandonmartinez.com/2015/08/20/enable-gzip-compression-for-azure-web-apps/